# Electronics - Matlab - I would like to us a Kalman Filter in a GPS doppler speed signal

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I would like to use the Kalman Filter in the GPS Doppler speed. Even if I read some tutorials in the web, I have no idea how to do it.

Is there a matlab script that can do it only by given in input the GPS speed. Maybe I have to precise the sample frequency also ?

Comment: can you give some hint about how your data is formed? Do you receive only the speed or also the position? how many dimensions?

Comment: thank you for answering. I receive the speed and also the position (latitude, longitude). I have 2 dimensions. @Vahid

Comment: Are your searching for a script where you only have to input your GPS-Data and the return values are the filtered longitude, latitude?

Comment: If it's possible yes, and also understand better this kind of filter.. @bushmills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the minimal matlab code with `vision.KalmanFilter` class. assuming your measurements are column vectors of matrix `data` [latitude, latitude_speed, longitude, longitude_speed]'. constant velocity model is assumed here. You should define `ProcessNise`, `MeasurementNoise` and the initialization yourself.

```
data = randn(4,100); % load your data here

delta = 1; % sampling frequency
% state model asuming constant velocity
stateModel = [1 delta 0 0    ; 
              0 1     0 0    ;
              0 0     1 delta;
              0 0     0 1    ];
% measurements are simply the state
measurementModel = eye(4);

kalman = vision.KalmanFilter(stateModel, ...
                             measurementModel, ...
                             'ProcessNoise',1, ...
                             'MeasurementNoise',1);

%initialize
kalman.State = [0; 0; 0; 0];
kalman.StateCovariance = eye(4);

T = size(data,2); % length of measurements
filtered = [];
for t=1:T
    measurement = data(:,t);
    kalman.predict(); % prediction
    kalman.correct(measurement);
    filtered = [filtered, kalman.State];
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Vahid. This looks great!! However I don't have the longitude and latitude speed. I just have one value for the speed (I don't know the direction). Maybe I can use the same code but stateModel is 3*3 instead of 4*4. Do you think it could work correctly ?

Comment: @YLR in that case you can still use the same `stateModel` I wrote here, i.e. with longitude and latitude speed. But your `measurementModel` will not be linear anymore and Kalman filter does not applied. you may use Extended Kalman filter or particle filter in this case.